# Selenium+Python: mycode not work properly in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

**I have some code it's not running in for loop** Basically, the function is that the script opens the Facebook and login it and then redirects into the followed group and posts a message into the followed group and then do it again with another FB id. it runs correctly if I don't use a for loop. but if I use it it login FB first time but give me an error after login.

## Error

```
[5924:7632:1019/091938.254:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(228)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report 
that this ends.
[5924:7632:1019/091938.258:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(231)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[5924:5408:1019/091938.363:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:19:38.364] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[5924:7632:1019/091938.366:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(234)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[5924:5408:1019/091938.773:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:19:38.773] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1073 Getting Default Adapter failed.
[5924:7632:1019/091939.452:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(238)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.   
[11928:9912:1019/092108.770:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

## Edited Code

```
# Imports 
from typing_extensions import runtime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidArgumentException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os, wget, time, clipboard
# MESSAGE 
text_to_post = 'Hi, I am New In This Group'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)

id_pass = open('ids.pwd','r')
idpass = id_pass.readlines(5)
for id_pass_ in idpass:
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")

        username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='email']")))
        password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='pass']")))

        i,d = id_pass_.split('.')
        print(i,d)
        username.clear()
        username.send_keys(i)
        password.clear()
        password.send_keys(d)

        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
        time.sleep(10)
        a = driver.current_url

        if a == 'https://www.facebook.com/':
            driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/groups/icdeveloper0")
        else:
            print('ACCOUNT BANNED')
```

## Complete Code

```
# Imports 
from typing_extensions import runtime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidArgumentException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os, wget, time, clipboard
# MESSAGE 
text_to_post = 'Hi, I am New In This Group'
count = 0

# disable the notification
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

# Specify the path to chromedriver.exe
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)

id_pass = open('ids.pwd','r')
idpass = id_pass.readlines(5)
count = 0
for id_pass_ in idpass:
    count +=1
    try:        
        #open the webpage
        time.sleep()
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")

        #target username
        username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='email']")))
        password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='pass']")))

        # Click the post box
        # count +=1
        i,d = id_pass_.split('.')
        # i,d = 'my_id','my_pass'
        print(i,d)
        #enter username and password
        username.clear()
        username.send_keys(i)
        password.clear()
        password.send_keys(d)

        #target the login button and click it
        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
        time.sleep(10)
        a = driver.current_url

        if a == 'https://www.facebook.com/':
            driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/groups/icdeveloper0")

            time.sleep(10)
            try:
                post_class = 'oajrlxb2 b3i9ofy5 qu0x051f esr5mh6w e9989ue4 r7d6kgcz rq0escxv nhd2j8a9 j83agx80 p7hjln8o kvgmc6g5 cxmmr5t8 oygrvhab hcukyx3x cxgpxx05 d1544ag0 sj5x9vvc tw6a2znq i1ao9s8h esuyzwwr f1sip0of lzcic4wl l9j0dhe7 abiwlrkh p8dawk7l bp9cbjyn orhb3f3m czkt41v7 fmqxjp7s emzo65vh btwxx1t3 buofh1pr idiwt2bm jifvfom9 kbf60n1y'
                post_class = post_class.replace(' ', '.')
                click_post = driver.find_element_by_class_name(post_class)
                click_post.click()
                time.sleep(5)
                
                post_content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('notranslate._5rpu')
                post_content = driver.switch_to_active_element()
                post_content.send_keys(text_to_post)
                time.sleep(10)
                
                soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
                all_pc = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': re.compile("^mount_0_0_")})
                id_ = str(all_pc[0].get('id'))
                xpath = '//*[@id="' + id_ + '"]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div'
                post = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
                post.click()
                time.sleep(10)
                
            except:
                print("Something went wrong, exiting script to avoid conflicts")

        else:
            print('ACCOUNT BANNED')
    except InvalidArgumentException as e:
       print(e)
```

## ids.pwd (its a text file)

```
    my_id1.my_pass1
    my_id2.my_pass2
    my_id3.my_pass3
    my_id4.my_pass4
```

## Complete Output

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55982/devtools/browser/02d31a0f-9325-4a9c-8440-d38ba5340521
03065509734 03065509734

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\abdul\OneDrive\Desktop\Facebook-group-automation-python---Web-Automation-master\MY NEW APP\run.py", line 10, in <module>
    main_cli.run()
  File "c:\Users\abdul\OneDrive\Desktop\Facebook-group-automation-python---Web-Automation-master\MY NEW APP\main_cli.py", line 47, in run    
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until       
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

PS C:\Users\abdul\OneDrive\Desktop\Facebook-group-automation-python---Web-Automation-master\MY NEW APP> [5924:7632:1019/091938.254:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(228)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report 
that this ends.
[5924:7632:1019/091938.258:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(231)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[5924:5408:1019/091938.363:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:19:38.364] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[5924:7632:1019/091938.366:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(234)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[5924:5408:1019/091938.773:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:19:38.773] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1073 Getting Default Adapter failed.
[5924:7632:1019/091939.452:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(238)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.   
[11928:9912:1019/092108.770:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: seems like a standard timeout exception...  why only 2 seconds for the button click?  Btw, you should not do this.  Your account(s) will get suspended a bit because they'll think you've been hacked.